# understanding jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been assigned a project which involves a lot of jQuery. I am quite easy with it but the previous developer used the following code which is totally new to me and I am not aware of what it does.

```
$.extend({
    ay: {
        ajaxRequest: {
            abort: function(){}
        }
    }
});
```

I can tell that `ay` is directory name in which all of the project's configuration files and templates are. Can anybody explain this code? Thanks

I've also seen this code in the project:

```
$.ay.ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    data: {
        ay: {
            action: 'update',
            element: {
                id: $(this).data().id
            },
            input: {
                name: $(this).attr('name'),
                value: $(this).val()
            }
        }
    },
    type: 'post'
});​
```

In this sample code, there is no url or path to php script, can you explain this as well?

Comment: ay is definitely NOT a directory name.

Comment: it sure is my friend....

Answer (score 4):

He's using [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to extend jQuery to add an `ay` attribute, which is an object with an `ajaxRequest` attribute, which is another object with an `abort` attribute which is an empty function (noop).

So you could do;

```
jQuery.ay.ajaxRequest.abort();
```

If you wanted, which would do absolutely nothing.

As to why this is useful; you'll have to inspect the rest of the code to see where he's calling it.

For more info on extending jQuery see [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

**EDIT:** To address the second part, if he's extending jQuery before you see that code, then he's replacing the `ajaxRequest` with the jqXHR returned by `jQuery.ajax()`. If he's extending jQuery after that code, then he's overwriting the `abort()` method to do nothing; basically no-one will be able to cancel the AJAX request.

Using `jQuery.extend()` to do this is quite weird, I'd do:

```
jQuery.ay.ajaxRequest.abort = jQuery.noop;
```

He must be declaring the URL for that AJAX request using [`jQuery.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) (which sets AJAX defaults).

Comment: In humorous hindsight, that's a lot of work for doing absolutely nothing.

Comment: `$.ay.ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            data: {
                ay: {
                    action: 'update', 
                    element: {
                        id: $(this).data().id
                    }, 
                    input: {
                        name: $(this).attr('name'), 
                        value: $(this).val()
                    }
                }
            },
            type: 'post'
        });`
in this sample code, there is no url or path to php script, can you explain this ?

Comment: there is only action update ? how ajax call will go to that particuler update action ?

Comment: @jugnu: Maybe he's declaring the URL using [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) (which sets AJAX defaults).

Comment: i appreciate your guidelines, my question still the same, how that ajax request will go to the update action,update action described in the same script from where onclick event is triggered

Comment: @jugnu: You must have a AJAX complete handler somewhere which inspects what `update` action was passed. Alternatively, the server could be returning data which the complete handler is using to call the `update` action.

Answer (score 1):

The code adds a property called ay to The jQuery object ($) making code such as `$.ay.ajaxRequest.abort()` possible.

If you pass one argument to extend that argument will extend the jQuery namespace it self. 
That means each property of the argument will be cloned to the jQuery object. In your case there's a single property called ay which is cloned to the jQuery object. Calling extend with an object that has one property is equal to

```
$.ay = {
          ajaxRequest : {...}
       };
```